# how to access query string in controller and routes of laravel

Tags: laravel, query-string

when I will click on a tag it go to specific url if no id found then go to reference
My view

```
<a href="{{URL::to('user/')}}/?reference={{$user->username}}">
                    go there
                  </a>
```

my route

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/{reference?}', 'UserController@index')->name('/user');
```

Comment: Please clarify your question  is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: Your given route and href is different here. The href could be `{{URL::to('user/'.$user->id.'/'.$user->username)}} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is considered part of the inputs and not part of the URI for routing. If you want the 'id' part of the URI to be optional you would have to adjust your definition. Then in your controller you can access your `reference` query string parameter.

```
Route::get('user/{id?}', 'UserController@index')->name('user');

public function index(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $reference = $request->input('reference');
    ...
}
```